# Getting unexpected "undefined reference to" errors when compiling with a static library

Tags: c++, g++

I've been trying to make a static library out of this: https://github.com/onlinecity/cpp-smpp , as I'd like to make a single file executable that uses it.

So far I have gone into src/smpp/ and created the .o files with:

```
g++-5 -c *.cpp -std=c++11 -I.
```

Then made them into an .a file with:

```
ar rvs libsmpp.a *.o
```

Then I'm trying to compile a small main.cpp file that uses the library with this:

```
g++-5 main.cpp -I/usr/local/include -static libsmpp.a -lboost_system -lboost_regex -lboost_date_time -lpthread -lm -lglog -lgflags -std=c++11
```

And I get some undefined reference errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libstdc++.a(condition_variable.o): In function `std::condition_variable::~condition_variable()':
(.text._ZNSt18condition_variableD2Ev+0x1): undefined reference to `pthread_cond_destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libstdc++.a(condition_variable.o): In function `std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&)':
(.text._ZNSt18condition_variable4waitERSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE+0x8): undefined reference to `pthread_cond_wait'
libsmpp.a(smppclient.o): In function `smpp::SmppClient::sendPdu(smpp::PDU&)':
smppclient.cpp:(.text+0x22a1): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const*, int)'
smppclient.cpp:(.text+0x22b0): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
smppclient.cpp:(.text+0x22d4): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
smppclient.cpp:(.text+0x2534): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
libsmpp.a(smppclient.o): In function `smpp::SmppClient::readPdu(bool const&)':
smppclient.cpp:(.text+0x29d8): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const*, int)'
smppclient.cpp:(.text+0x29e7): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::stream()'
smppclient.cpp:(.text+0x2a0b): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
smppclient.cpp:(.text+0x2a48): undefined reference to `google::LogMessage::~LogMessage()'
libsmpp.a(smppclient.o): In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_event::~posix_event()':
smppclient.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail11posix_eventD2Ev[_ZN5boost4asio6detail11posix_eventD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `pthread_cond_destroy'
libsmpp.a(smppclient.o): In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_event::posix_event()':
smppclient.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail11posix_eventC2Ev[_ZN5boost4asio6detail11posix_eventC5Ev]+0x2e): undefined reference to `pthread_cond_init'
libsmpp.a(smppclient.o): In function `void boost::asio::detail::posix_event::wait<boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex> >(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>&)':
smppclient.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail11posix_event4waitINS1_11scoped_lockINS1_11posix_mutexEEEEEvRT_[_ZN5boost4asio6detail11posix_event4waitINS1_11scoped_lockINS1_11posix_mutexEEEEEvRT_]+0x5f): undefined reference to `pthread_cond_wait'
libsmpp.a(timeformat.o): In function `boost::date_time::month_formatter<boost::gregorian::greg_month, boost::date_time::iso_format<char>, char>::format_month(boost::gregorian::greg_month const&, std::ostream&)':
timeformat.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9date_time15month_formatterINS_9gregorian10greg_monthENS0_10iso_formatIcEEcE12format_monthERKS3_RSo[_ZN5boost9date_time15month_formatterINS_9gregorian10greg_monthENS0_10iso_formatIcEEcE12format_monthERKS3_RSo]+0x33): undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string() const'
timeformat.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9date_time15month_formatterINS_9gregorian10greg_monthENS0_10iso_formatIcEEcE12format_monthERKS3_RSo[_ZN5boost9date_time15month_formatterINS_9gregorian10greg_monthENS0_10iso_formatIcEEcE12format_monthERKS3_RSo]+0x56): undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It compiles fine when I link to a dynamic version of the smpp library, although that's made using the cmake files included with the smpp lib. I didn't know how to modify them to output a static library, so I just used the g++ command at the top, and added the libraries listed in them (like glog) in the main.cpp compile command.

The "undefined reference to google::logMessage" seems especially strange, as I'm pretty sure thats part of glog, which is definitely loaded and included in the smppclient.cpp file itself.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can't just take code meant to build a shared library and compile it for a static library.  There may be preprocessor switches you need to set first.  The worst case scenario is that you may have to make source code changes.  I would go to the authors of the library and ask if it is possible to make a static library out of their code base, and if so, what changes need to be made.  If they can't answer, then you're on your own as this would be uncharted territory for them.

Comment: Try linking pthread with the smpp code before you put it into the smpp library. if the first error you get is resolved then you can repeat the process to resolve the other errors.

Comment: I was unaware of that Paul, thanks, I will check with them.

Comment: Jay, do you mean add -lpthread when compiling the .o files?